# Berkshelf: Install java 8

Tags: chef-infra, berkshelf

My berkshelf folder structure is like:

```
│   Berksfile
│   Berksfile.lock
│   chefignore
│   knife.rb
│   living.pem
│   metadata.rb
├───recipes
│       default.rb
│       elasticsearch.rb
│       java.rb
```

The content of each `recipe.rb` is:

`default.rb` content file:

```
include_recipe 'berk::java'
include_recipe 'berk::elasticsearch'
```

`java.rb` content file:

```
include_recipe 'java'
```

`elasticsearch.rb` content file:

```
include_recipe 'elasticsearch'

elasticsearch_user 'elasticsearch' do
  username 'elasticsearch'
  groupname 'elasticsearch'
  shell '/bin/bash'
  comment 'Elasticsearch User'

  action :create
end

elasticsearch_install 'my_es_installation' do
  type 'package' # type of install
  version '5.2.0'
  action :install # could be :remove as well
end

...
```

I would like to change java settings in order to use java 8 of oracle. I know that probably it seems a very straightforward question, nevertheless, I've really stuck on that issue.

I've tried to add these lines in `java.rb`:

```
node.default['java']['install_flavor'] = 'oracle'
node.default['java']['jdk_version'] = '8'
node.default['java']['oracle']['accept_oracle_download_terms'] = true
```

And also I've tried:

```
node.override['java']['install_flavor'] = 'oracle'
node.override['java']['jdk_version'] = '8'
node.override['java']['oracle']['accept_oracle_download_terms'] = true
```

Nevertheless, Java 6 is installed:

```
==> default:   * log[jdk-version-changed] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
==> default: Recipe: java::openjdk
==> default:   * yum_package[java-1.6.0-openjdk] action install
==> default: [2017-02-21T15:10:33+00:00] INFO: yum_package[java-1.6.0-openjdk] installing java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.41-1.13.13.1.el7_3 from updates repository
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't override attributes in recipe (out of specific cases), use an `attributes/default.rb` file to define those attributes at default level will be enough and all will be right.

You're probably overriding the attributes after the inclusion of java recipe, hence your problem, attributes files are all read before any recipe is compiled, include_recipe compile the target recipe as soon as they are seen so if your java.rb file looks like:

```
include_recipe 'java'

node.default['java']['install_flavor'] = 'oracle'
node.default['java']['jdk_version'] = '8'
node.default['java']['oracle']['accept_oracle_download_terms'] = true
```

the resources of the java recipe will be compiled before the attributes are updated.

So create a `attributes` directory and a file `default.rb` within with:

```
default['java']['install_flavor'] = 'oracle'
default['java']['jdk_version'] = '8'
default['java']['oracle']['accept_oracle_download_terms'] = true
```

And you have java 8 installed.

Files in the attributes directory are loaded in alphanumeric order (matters if two files set different values for the same attribute), you may name them however you wish, you can have a `java.rb` and `elasticsearch.rb` if you wish to separate the attributes for each recipe also.